# Convergence in measure/probability vs a.e. convergence

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $\{X_n\}$ be a sequence of i.i.d. real random variables. We say $X_n$ converges to a real random variable $X$ in probability if for all $\epsilon > 0$
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} P(|X_n - X| < \epsilon) = 0$$
and $X_n$ converges to $X$ a.e. if
$$P(\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} X_n = X) = 1.$$

From measure theory, I've always thought of convergence in measure as saying the measure of the set $$\{x \mid |X_n - X| > \epsilon\}$$ decreases with $n$, but the set might "jump around" (e.g. the well known sliding block example as discussed in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1415891/almost-everywhere-convergence-versus-convergence-in-measure)). In contrast, a.e. convergence requires this set to be fixed in some sense.

On [Terence Tao's blog](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2015/10/23/275a-notes-3-the-weak-and-strong-law-of-large-numbers/) he says

> ...roughly speaking, convergence in probability is good for controlling how a single random variable $X_n$ is close to its putative limiting value $X$, while almost sure convergence is good for controlling how the entire *tail* $(X_n)_{n \geq N}$ of a random sequence of random variables is close to its putative limit $X$.

I have never thought about convergence in measure/probability as describing a single element $X_n$ in the sequence $\{X_n\}$. What does Tao mean by this? Also, how does a.e. convergence control the entire tail of the sequence?

Comment: I think what he means is that if $x \in \{ |X_n - X|  > \varepsilon \}$, $X_n$ must be close to $X$ only at this point, but it has no implication on $X_{n+1}$ (it has other points which it needs to be close to $X$). In contrast, if $x \in \{ \lim X_n = X \}$ , then $X_k$ must be close to $X$ for all $k$ large enough, so this refers to the "tail" in that sense. 
Its more of "comparing the sets" than "comparing the types of limits", if that's clear enough..

Comment: @Amit Thank you very much! That helped clarify that passage for me.